# Does anybody know how to generate a set of random numbers in vb.net between two numbers that follows Poisson distribution?

Tags: vb.net

The numbers should be discrete and have an upper bound and lower bound.

I am using the probability distribution formula of poison distribution and using it in my code but I am not getting the result.

Comment: Show us the code with a clear explanation of exactly how the results aren’t meeting your expectations

Comment: Note that the Poisson distribution is _unbounded_ (it can take any integer 0 or greater); what you're seeking is a _truncated_ Poisson distribution.

Comment: You can inherit the `Random` class and override the `Sample` method to control how numbers are generated. You can implement some form of weighting there to skew the distribution.

Comment: If you can't show us the code you're using, you could try using [Math.NET](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/Poisson.htm).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what you mean by follows Poisson distribution? but if you want to generate random values in vb.net between two numbers you could use something like so

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim LowerBound As Integer = 15
    Dim UpperBound As Integer = 30
    Dim Result As Integer = CInt(LowerBound + (Rnd() * ((UpperBound + 1) - LowerBound)))
    TextBox1.Text = Result
End Sub
```

and the updated version from Rnd() is the Random().Next instruction as Hursey commented which can be used like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim LowerBound As Integer = 15
    Dim UpperBound As Integer = 30
    ' Instantiate random number generator using system-supplied value as seed.
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim Result As Integer = rand.Next(LowerBound, UpperBound)
    rand = Nothing
    TextBox1.Text = Result
End Sub
```

Comment: Could probably stand to do some reading on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0. Rnd() is obsolete and only included for backwards compatibility now.  Random.Next() also has upper and lower bounds built in

Comment: i know but that 3 letter instruction got my heart for decades. and i'am glad they didn't remove it from the .net framework